# How can I download only one Angular Material component and not the entire library?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to use Angular Material only the DatePicker component for a project that I'm doing with latest version of Angular.

Can I download only one Material component or do I have to download the entire library to be able to use it?

I look forward to your help, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the entire library, but only import what you use.

You install the entire library by running `ng add @angular/material`. However, in your module, you only include the components you need. So your module would only import `MatDatepickerModule` and not all the components.

Comment: PMO1948: Thanks you very much for your help :)